# PHP float numbers not adding correctly - decimal value missing

Tags: php, floating-point, number-formatting

I am trying to get the total of my variables containing numbers, some may be decimals.  I need this to be to two decimal places and am using the number_format() function.

```
$total =  $order->order->net+$order->order->deductions+$order->order->vat+$order->order->postage+$order->order->postage_tax; 
            echo number_format((float)$total, 2, '.', '');?>
```

I have noticed the following values do not add up correctly and seems to be ignoring the decimal. The total should be 118.50 but instead I get 118.00.

> 100+0+17.5+1+0

I have researched this and found the below

http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

I am a little confused by it.  Can anyone explain what I need to do?

***EDIT**
Below is dump of the $order variable showing the numbers I am trying to add up.   You can see the 17.5 is 17.5 and not 17.  Is it because they are specified as being strings perhaps?

`object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (21) { ["id"]=> string(6) "922704" ["shopkeeper_orderno"]=> string(4) "1001" ["customer"]=> string(6) "797893" ["creationdate"]=> string(16) "29-05-2012 11:55" ["net"]=> string(3) "100" ["vat"]=> string(4) "17.5" ["status"]=> string(1) "1" ["isnew"]=> string(1) "0" ["deductions"]=> string(1) "0" ["postage"]=> string(1) "1" ["paymentmethod"]=> string(20) "PayPal " ["instructions"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#17 (0) { } [2]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#22 (1) { ["items"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#30 (9) { ["id"]=> string(7) "1384486" ["headerID"]=> string(6) "922704" ["productID"]=> string(7) "4959678" ["description"]=> string(13) "Wedding dress" ["net"]=> string(3) "100" ["vat"]=> string(4) "17.5" ["qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["formID"]=> string(2) "-1" ["options"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#31 (1) { ["options"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#32 (6) { ["id"]=> string(6) "519981" ["orderDetailsID"]=> string(7) "1384486" ["optionid"]=> string(6) "646934" ["optionCost"]=> string(1) "0" ["optionVAT"]=> string(1) "0" ["customText"]=> string(9) "size : 12" } [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#33 (6) { ["id"]=> string(6) "519982" ["orderDetailsID"]=> string(7) "1384486" ["optionid"]=> string(6) "647285" ["optionCost"]=> string(1) "0" ["optionVAT"]=> string(1) "0" ["customText"]=> string(14) "Colour : Ivory" } } } } } } ["postage_tax"]=> string(1) "0" ["dispatched"]=> string(1) "0" ["paybyotherid"]=> string(2) "-1" ["wheredidyouhearid"]=> string(2) "-1"` }

Comment: 118.50 is massively different from 118.00 so I dont think its a floating point fault here. It only occurs on really large/small numbers. Can you give a a var_dump of $order please?

Comment: If you pass the numbers in raw, [it works](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UujdC0). Echo out all the variables used in the calculation and verify that they really are what you think/say they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure your all of theese vars are **int** or **float** type?
Check the type as

```
var_dump($order->order->net, $order->order->deductions, $order->order->vat,$order->order->postage, $order->order->postage_tax);
```

if you used `number_format` for these vars they may be string, use [floatval](http://php.net/floatval)().

check the examples,

```
$a = 100+0+"17,5"+1+0;
    var_dump($a);
```

Result : int(118)

```
$b = 100+0+17.5+1+0;
    var_dump($b);
```

Result : float(118.5)

Comment: The numbers are type string.  I have had to convert to float and it now works. thanks

Answer (score 6):

you can use round and then number format:

```
  $total = 100+0+17.5+1+0.2;
//echo number_format((float)$total);  //119
  echo number_format(round((float)$total,2),2);  //118.50
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the value coming for varriable `$order->order->vat`. I think this is not coming 17.5 because if We assign the value you assign to varriable and add them it shows correct answer.

```
$a = 100;
$b = 0;
$c = 17.5;
$d = 1;
$e = 0;
```

$total = $a + $b + $c + $d + $e;
   echo number_format((float)$total, 2, '.', ''); //118.50 (Answer)

Or Use `floatval($var)`  for getting float value of variable.

```
$total =  $order->order->net+$order->order->deductions+floatval($order->order->vat)+$order->order->postage+$order->order->postage_tax; 
 echo number_format((float)$total, 2, '.', '');?>
```

I hope it will be work.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for exact value without any correction or round you should use the [bcadd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php) following function to get the actual two decimal point

```
$total =  $order->order->net+$order->order->deductions+$order->order->vat+$order->order->postage+$order->order->postage_tax; 
$total=bcadd(0,$total,2);
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the function you want for rounding to 2dp is "round" and not "number_format".

Visibly, in your echo, they will both do the same, though. Round will permanently adjust the number if you want to do future processing with it.

Having said that, I can't see any error in your code, or any reason why the 0.5 should be dropped. I suggest you check that $order->order->vat is actually 17.5 and not 17. If it is 17, then chase it backwards to find where you've integered that (e.g. in a database or in a input validation function, for example)